# Check condition in a for statement

Tags: c, search

I wrote a function that checks if a number exists in an interval.
What is the best way to stop searching? This one:

```
for (i = a; i <= b; i++) {
  fi = f(i);
  if (fi == c) {
    j = i;
    break;
  }
}
```

or this one?

```
for (i = a; (i <= b) && (IsFound == 0); i++) {
  fi = f(i);
  if (fi == c) {
    j = i;
    IsFound = 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: I agree with the answers saying "break." But you would rather do `!IsFound` than `IsFound == 0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick answer : `break;` is better

Why , as soon as break is reached code will escape the loop. But in second choice you need to reach `for` loops condition checking state

[Quoting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wt88dxx6.aspx)

> The break statement terminates the execution of the nearest enclosing do, for, switch, or while statement in which it appears. Control passes to the statement that follows the terminated statement.

In code explanation

Option I

```
for ( i = a; i <= b; i++ ){
  fi = f ( i );
  if ( fi == c ){
     j = i;
     break; // Simply exit from here , no more continuing
  }
}
```

Option II

```
for ( i = a; (i <= b) && (IsFound == 0); i++ ) // Need to reach here for exit
{
  fi = f ( i );    
  if ( fi == c ){
    j = i;
    IsFound = 1; // you set flag here but need to continue till for loop condition checking
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go for #1 way because:

- In second, you defined a new variable isFound and maintaining it.
- You are adding an overhead by checking with isFound variable for each value of i.
- You will have an additional check and increment at the end where because of isFound variable you will break of for loop.

Answer (score -1):

Break is the best way to stop the loop.

Consider if you are doing the lot of work after that if condition, you are having the more code. If you use the variable after enabling that condition will execute.
It not come out from the loop after executing.

If you use the break. That time itself loop will break. It come out from the loop.